# How to hide and show the view in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Am using ViewPager to show bunch of images by one by one.Am customize the ViewPager use **PagerContainer** [by refer this example](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1).In ViewPager have two image view in default the both image view are visible.But i want to invisible one image view onselectedpage in ViewPager.For example view pager current position in 2 means the blur image in 2nd position is going to invisible.in all other position the blur image is visible.I don't how to do.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

**View Pager Declaration**

```
ema = new Executive_member_adapter(getActivity());

executive_cont = (PagerContainer)findViewById(R.id.executive_memeber_container);
executive_members = executive_cont.getViewPager();

executive_members.setAdapter(ema);
executive_members.setOffscreenPageLimit(ema.getCount());

executive_members.setPageMargin(15);
executive_members.setClipChildren(false);
executive_members.setOnPageChangeListener(ema);
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class Executive_member_adapter  extends PagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener{

LayoutInflater inflater;
Activity activity;

ImageView members_img,blur_img;

int photos[] = {R.drawable.pic1,R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3,R.drawable.pic4,R.drawable.pic5,R.drawable.pick6};

public Executive_member_adapter(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return photos.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

   ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    View itemView;
    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.executive_members_pic, container, false);

    members_img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.memebers_image);
    members_img.setBackgroundResource(photos[position]);

   blur_img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.blur_image);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the array from which you are showing the images, you can dynamically add/remove the image that you want to hide or show.

Comment: I want to hide and show.in default two images views in each page.in selected selected page to visible only one image view.

Answer (score 0):

Dit you mean something like this?
On the selected page a ImageView becomes invisible. In this case the ViewPager got 4 pages.

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            blur_img.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            blur_img.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            break;
        case 2:
            blur_img.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 3:
            blur_img.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            break;

    }
```

Comment: no.on selected page only to invisible the image.Visible on all other pages.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, you say this to the other post: "_I want to hide and show.in default two images views in each page.in selected selected page to visible only one image view._" In the example I gave you can hide and show the images per page. You can show both or hide 1 depending on the page selected.

Comment: am customize the view-pager with two image view.i mentioned in pager adapter class (members_img,blur image). For example view pager current position in 2 means the **blur image** in 2nd position is going to invisible.in all other position the **blur image** is visible.

Comment: Edited my answer, dit you mean this?